# Mysql join 4 tables can it be done in one query

Tags: mysql, database

My database

```
category_group(id,name)
category(id,name,cat_group_id)
topic(id,name,cat_id)
comment(id,name,topic_id)
```

I want to get:

```
Category Group 1
=====================
Category 1
Count topic | Count comment
-------------------
Category 2
Count topic | Count comment


Category Group 2
=====================
Category 3
Count topic | Count comment
-------------------
Category 4
Count topic | Count comment
```

I can only do with a lot of different query but I think it is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

If all the table are strictly related you can use inner join

```
    select a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*
    from category as a
    inner join category_group as b on a.cat_group_id = b id
    inner join topic as c on a.id = c.cat_id
    inner join comment as d.topic_id = c.id
```

else where need use left join

Then for in your case you can do this

```
    select b.name,  a.name, count(d.*) as count_commect, count(c.*) as count_topic
    from category as a
    inner join category_group as b on a.cat_group_id = b id
    inner join topic as c on a.id = c.cat_id
    inner join comment as d.topic_id = c.id
    group by a.name, b.name
    order by a.name, b.name
```

Comment: what about counts and  category_group order?

Comment: according to the question,  should be two counters - topics and comments

Comment: something such count(distinct topic.id). But i'm not sure that it a good aproach to do this in one query